# Directly render d3 interactive charts from a nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am able to render charts but interactive events like `mouseover` don't work.

I have used codes of [this sample](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569) but this code is ignored when I `mouseover`, `mouseout` or `move`.

```
  .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
  .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
  .on("mousemove", mousemove);
```

Comment: In which browser did you run the code? your code is exactly the same? console error? console error?

Comment: there is no error in the console. I rendered this on the server side

Comment: When you say you rendered it server-side, what was the output?  Just SVG?